# How do detect that cloud-init completed initialization

Tags: provisioning, configuration-management, cloud-init

I am configuring an OpenStack box using cloud-init/cloud-config. I intend to wait until it is fully configured before I start using it.

This is not all that hard to do using some marker file or detecting if the cloud-init process is still running, though it seems quite cumbersome to do that in every cloud-init script. Is there some recommended way? Natively supported by cloud-init, ideally?

Answer (score 22):

The following command does the trick:

```sh
cloud-init status --wait
```

From https://ubuntu.com/blog/cloud-init-v-18-2-cli-subcommands:

> `cloud-init status` gives simple human-readable or programmatic output
> for what cloud-init is doing and whether it has finished successfully.
> It can be used as a sanity check on a machine or in scripts to block
> until cloud-init has completed successfully.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to let the cloud-init [phone home](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/17.2/topics/modules.html#phone-home) once it finishes:

```yaml
phone_home:
    url: https://example.com/$INSTANCE_ID/
    post:
        - pub_key_dsa
        - instance_id
        - fqdn
    tries: 10
```

Comment: Sounds nice, link is dead. Prime example of why you need to include your answer here on SO.

Comment: Good point, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As @flyxiao pointed out, cloud-init put status information into a dedicated directory on a filesystem: `/run/cloud-init/` (preferred over `/var/lib/cloud/data/` as it is guaranteed to describe last init process). `status.json` contains detailed about all init phases and `result.json` denotes the whole init is completed. The [project documentation](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-init-dev/cloud-init/trunk/view/head:/doc/status.txt) suggest a python script to detect cloud-init completion:

```
 fin = "/run/cloud-init/result.json"
 if os.path.exists(fin):

   ret = json.load(open(fin, "r"))

   if len(ret['v1']['errors']):

     print "Finished with errors:" + "\n".join(ret['v1']['errors'])

   else:

     print "Finished no errors"

 else:

   print "Not Finished"
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful. Also needs to be checked that cloud-init is installed and enabled IMO :) .. in case somebody is using a mix of images with and without cloud-init.

Comment: Apparently, there is now a dedicated command for that - `cloud-init status`. More information is available [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/cloud-init-v-18-2-cli-subcommands).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is to set a tag on the instance so you can poll for its existence.

If you have a Linux host, do this last:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources `ec2metadata --instance-id` --tags Key=BootstrapStatus,Value=complete
```

This avoids needing to set up a network endpoint, creating a point of failure, or SSHing in, creating a need to secure credentials.

Comment: Right, though it require cloud-init assistance and the machine able to talk to cloud provider.

Comment: This will have to be run from the userdata (as the last line), which does not guarantee that cloud-init has completed (it may do more after the userdata has been run, such as printing ec2 instance fingerprints, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the /var/lib/cloud/data/status.json for cloud-init status.
Or if the host is using upstart, add one init process in /etc/init/newprocess.conf and newprocess.conf should be started after cloud-final.

Comment: I am using cloud-init 0.7.6 on RHEL and there is no `newprocess.conf` file. Can you provide documentation link? I will have a look at `/var/lib/cloud/data/*.json`.

Comment: Maybe /var/lib/cloud/data/*.json matches you, i need clear newprocess.conf solution. If your RHEL uses the upstart as the OS init, you may change /etc/init/cloud-init-local.conf (remove one temp file), /etc/init/cloud-final.conf (generate one temp file). if your RHEL uses the systemd as the OS init. Change cloud-init-local.service and cloud-final.service.